# With MVC/Entity Framework, how does one manage housekeeping tasks in the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

My understanding is that only one model can be passed to the view at a time.  The problem with this that I see is that I am being forced to pass the Entity Framework model, and not any model that will manage housekeeping in the view.  Here is what I mean:

You need to make a page that allows someone to submit Cars to the database.  Along with the form fields (e.g. CarName, CarMake, CarYear) you also need a checkbox at the bottom of the page called "Remember Values" which when checked will "remember" the form values when the user clicks the Submit button at the bottom, so when they return all of their form data is still in the form fields.  Needless to say, this Remember Values variable is not part of the Entity Framework model- it is just a housekeeping variable for use in the view.

How would you guys handle adding this checkbox?  It feels like it should be part of the model, but I can't send two models to the view.  Am I just looking at this issue wrong?  What would you recommend?

.NET 4.5/MVC 5/EntityFramework 6

Comment: In my experience you would create a `view model` that has all of the required fields for a particular view and then map the values you want to an EF model in your controller/service layer/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good situation to be using ViewModels.

Build your ViewModels with all properties that you'd want to send/retrieve to/from your view. For example:

**EF Entity**

```
public class Car {
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Make { get; set; }
    public virtual string Year { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class AddCarViewModel {
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public bool RememberValues { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class CarController : Controller {
    // Constructor....

    public ActionResult Add() {
        var vm = new AddCarViewModel();

        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(AddCarViewModel vm) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            _carService.Save(vm.Car);
        }

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

Another good approach is to create Domain Transfer Objects, which are POCO classes to hold data that is transferred through the pipes. For example, in your business layer you may want to audit any changes to your Car model. So you may have properties like CreatedBy, CreatedDate, UpdatedBy, UpdatedDate, etc. (These properties are generally never displayed to the end-user but are important to store).

So you'd create the following classes:

```
public class Car {
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Make { get; set; }
    public virtual string Year { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }  
    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }  
    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }  
    public virtual DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }  
}

public class CarDTO {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

and you can use a library such as AutoMapper to map properties from Car -> CarDTO:

```
var car = _carService.GetCarById(id);

var carDTO = Mapper.Map<Car, CarDTO>(car);
```

This way, you can choose which properties you want exposed to your views by utilizing DTO's.

Comment: Great example, but the thing I don't understand is how I can save my local models to the EF context that expects domain models.  Also, how would I handle domain model fields like DateCreated or other fields what would not be populated by the View?  The ViewModel will lack many of the fields that are in the domain model.

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment, I don't see how this line of code will work: _carService.Save(vm.Car);  My understanding is that vm.Car can't be submitted to the database because it is a local type instead of a domain type.  Could you post more information about how _carService.Save(vm.Car); would work

Comment: Well if your EF entity is of type Car and your view model has a property of type Car, then there shouldn't be any reason why you couldnt persist vm.Car to the database.

Comment: If you are using the DTO approach, then you would have to convert CarDTO -> Car before you persist to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you *can* send two models to the view, if the model is actually something like a `Tuple`:

```
@model Tuple<SomeEFModel, SomeViewModel>
```

Though that's kind of ugly.  And if you're creating a view model anyway you might as well just make it a composite of the Entity Framework model.  Something like:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public SomeEFModel EFModel { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
    // other stuff...
}
```

Then just build an instance of that in the controller and send it to the model:

```
@model SomeViewModel
```

You could even just de-couple the EF model and the view model entirely, creating a custom view model that has everything for that view and then translating to/from that and the EF model at the controller level.  Ultimately it comes down to what implementation looks cleaner and is easier to maintain, which can differ from one context to another.

**Edit:**  Another option, if the models get unwieldy for whatever bits of the framework you're relying on, could be to separate your *outgoing* and *incoming* models.  For pushing data to the view, you can use the composite view model above.  But then when the data comes back from the view just use a normal Entity Framework model and a couple of additional parameters for your additional fields:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    // build the view model with the EF model as a property
    return View(someViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(SomeEFModel model, string someOtherProperty)
{
    // here you have an EF model from the view like normal
    // plus the additional property (however many you need)
    // you can even create a separate view model to collect the other properties
    // as long as the names are well defined, the model binder should build both
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like when an EF model is buried within a View Model, it loses its ability to be an EF model.  I mean how would one extract an EF model from a View Model and then insert it into the database using EF?

Comment: @flying227: I suppose that depends on how you're tracking your EF models and how your controller actions are structured.  How do you normally insert it into the database?  It seems to be that inserting `someObject.EFModel` is no different than inserting `someObject` itself.  C# wouldn't care if an object was a property on another object, the type is the same.  Another option (which I'll add to the answer) might be to just manually get the extra fields from the incoming model.

Comment: I guess my confusion here is how to insert my local object (e.g. MyProject.Models.Cars) into Entity Framework when EF wants an object of a different type (e.g. MyProject.Models.MyProjectEntities.Cars).  The way I would like to submit to the database is with private MyProjectContext db = new MyProjectContext();
db.Cars.Add(car);
db.SaveChanges();  (just 3 lines of code) but it seems like MVC is going to make me write out a whole lot more than just 3 lines to accomplish what I need (e.g. the model's data, the housekeeping data like Remember Values)

Comment: @flying227: Well, if you want to add more fields which are separate from the persisted model then of course you're going to have to write more lines of code.  I don't see what the problem is with the EF model, though.  If your controller action is currently correctly binding an instance of your EF model then it will continue to do so.  There's nothing special about an EF model vs. any other model when it's posted from a view.  The actual HTTP POST is just key/value pairs which the model binder uses to construct the expected object.  It can do that with any object.

Comment: Your edit about sending essentially an EF model back to the View plus separate additional fields is very interesting, but how would you structure the fields out in the View so that they could arrive in the controller separated (example: how would the Controller be able to separate out the SomeEFModel model from the someOtherProperty values?)  It seems like the controller wouldn't know one from the other.  See what I mean?

Comment: @flying227: The model binding is based entirely on the names of the `input` elements in the resulting HTML.  If the additional `input` element has a name that's not a property on the model but matches another parameter in the action method then it'll map that value to that parameter.  The HTML page doesn't contain an actual live instance of a model, all it contains are key/value pairs in form elements.

Comment: >"The actual HTTP POST is just key/value pairs which the model binder uses to construct the expected object. It can do that with any object."  I guess my confusion about this is how exactly do you convert an object from one type to another type (i.e. my local type to the EF type).  The controller is expecting only one type afterall (in this case I guess the EF type), so if I send the controller the other type, it will result in an error right?

Comment: @flying227: The *controller* isn't expecting anything. Any given *action method* has input parameters. Those parameters can be any type you want them to be. The model binder (which translates the incoming form key/value pairs into the method parameters) will simply make its best effort to map form input names to parameter objects. As long as there's no ambiguity in those names, it can successfully build the expected objects.

Answer (score 1):

I always create an additional model that I can convert to and from between the EF model.
This additional model gets passed to the View and holds al the neccesary properties like CarName, Carmake, CarYear, Remember and probably most importantly, the Id of that particular object.

So when the user submits, this model gets passed to the Post method where you can extract all the required properties. You fetch the database model using the Id from your DbContext and update the properties with the values that were just passed through.

Comment: Thanks, but how would one extract all of the required properties from the View Model and then add them to the EF model?  Also, this seems to be a whole lot of extra work (e.g. Creating essentially a duplicate of the EF model by hand, manually mapping the View Model to the EF Model, etc.)  I thought MVC was supposed to make things easier and faster, not harder and slower.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Using this approach would indeed mean to copy the properties by hand. (Of course, a method would make this an one time manual thing). I can see David's answer has some alternatives.

Comment: @flying227: You miss the idea of View Models. First, view models are not exactly like domain models, your example with additional checkbox is a good one. Second, you almost never copy manually but rather using automapper. Third, using your domain models in controllers could lead to over posting security issues.

Comment: @WiktorZychla the examples in my MVC book send domain models to the controllers all of the time.  Why would this result in a security issue?

Comment: By sending additional properties in a submit request of the EF Model by editing the POST. Properties that are not displayed, like Created date. Or as an example of a user, his username which you may not want to be changed.

Comment: @flying227: out of curiosity, what book is that?

Answer (score 1):

First, you absolutely should NOT be passing your EF models directly to your view, and you should certainly NOT be posting directly to your EF models.  This is essentially taking untrusted, unsanitized input and directly writing it to your data model with only bare minimal validation.

While this may work with simple models with no security or other ramifications, imagine a situation where you allowed a user to edit his profile information.  Further, imagine that in his profile you also stored information relating to his subscription information.  A specially crafted submit could alter his subscription information and give himself free access to your site, or worse...

Instead, you use view models.  Apart from the security aspects, view models are good because other than in very simple CRUD style sites, your views requirements are typically different from your data models requirements.  For instance, a particular field might be nullable in your data model, but you might want to make it required in your view.  If you pass your model directly, then you can't do that easily.

Finally, Aggregate view models aggregate many different submodels to provide an overall model for the view, which is what you are getting at.  You would then use a service layer, repository, or business logic layer to translate your view model to your data model, massaging data or applying logic as needed.